Unable to load array of random files correctly using PHP


<!doctype html>
<HTML lang="en"><!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/template.dwt.php" codeOutsideHTMLIsLocked="false" -->
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Title" -->
<TITLE>Hip Christmas: holiday music that rocks, rolls, swings, and twangs (www.hipchristmas.com)</TITLE>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Keywords" -->
<meta name="keywords" content="hip, Christmas, holiday, music, rock, roll, swing, twang, album, record, CD, compact disc, digital, download, MP3, streaming, review, collector, collecting, merry christmas, happy holidays, yule, winter, seasonal, Austin, Texas, Randy, Anthony, alternative, classic rock, country, disco, doo wop, easy listening, lounge, new wave, oldies, rhythm &amp; blues, rockabilly, power pop, punk, reggae, seventies, soul">
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Description" -->
<meta name="description" content="Hip Christmas is a website dedicated to holiday music that rocks, rolls, swings, and twangs. Read our reviews, search our extensive database of Christmas songs and albums, listen to our Christmas Jukebox, and click through to shop at the best online stores.">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="UaRm9SZGBplL31EX2bo83eWfh0qqBniS9YpweqsHUv0">
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
</script>
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="30 days">

<meta property="fb:admins" content="167593951846141,100009182578946">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Hip Christmas">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/get-url.php'); ?>">
<!--Generic Open Graph Images-->
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hipchristmas.com/images/og/logo.jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hipchristmas.com/images/og/beatles1.jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hipchristmas.com/images/og/jackson_five01.jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hipchristmas.com/images/og/lee_brenda3.jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.hipchristmas.com/images/og/presley2.jpg">
<!-- InstanceParam name="Script" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!--Main Content-->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Share" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Breadcrumbs" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Header" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Header-Bottom" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Navigation-Top" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Topper" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Introduction" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Body" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Review" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Expand" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Capsules" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Albums" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Songs" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Songs-Multiple" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="List" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Performances" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Performances-Multiple" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Tracks" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Tracks-Multiple" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Further" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Conclusion" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Old-News" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Navigation-Bottom" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!--Sidebar-->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Page-Menu" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Jukebox" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Buy" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Spotlight" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Optional" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Updates" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Facebook-High" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Sidebar" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Amazon-Search" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Amazon-Search-Plain" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Amazon-Search-Generic" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Amazon-Search-Digital" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Amazon-Recommended" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Buy2" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Spotlight2" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Optional2" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Updates2" type="boolean" value="true" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Facebook-Low" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<!-- InstanceParam name="Google-Side" type="boolean" value="false" -->
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/scripts.php"); ?>
<?php if (false) : ?>
<!-- Load css for dreamweaver only -->
<link href="/includes/design-time.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<?php endif; ?>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/facebook-script.php"); ?>
<LINK href="/includes/search.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- ////////// *** SKIP NAV *** \\\\\\\\\\ --> 
<A class="skippy visually-hidden-focusable" href="#content"><SPAN class="skippy-text">skip to content</SPAN></A> <A id="top"></A> 
<!-- ////////// *** BANNER *** \\\\\\\\\\ -->
<HEADER class="container-fluid">
  <DIV id="logo">
    <DIV id="google-top" class="desktop-only">
      <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/google-top.php"); ?>
    </DIV>
    <DIV id="banner" ROLE="banner">
      <DIV id="sitename"><A href="/index.php">Hip Christmas</A></DIV>
      <DIV id="slogan">holiday music that rocks, rolls, swings, and twangs</DIV>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</HEADER>

<!-- ////////// *** TOP NAV AND SEARCH *** \\\\\\\\\\ -->
<NAV class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top" ARIA-LABEL="primary"> <A class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">Hip Christmas</A>
  <BUTTON class="navbar-toggler" type="button" DATA-BS-TOGGLE="collapse" DATA-BS-TARGET="#navbarSupportedContent" ARIA-CONTROLS="navbarSupportedContent" ARIA-EXPANDED="false" ARIA-LABEL="Toggle navigation"> <SPAN class="navbar-toggler-icon"><I class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></I></SPAN> </BUTTON>
  <DIV class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <FORM action="/navigation/search.php" method="GET" ACCEPT-CHARSET="utf-8" target="_self" title="Search Hip Christmas" class="d-flex mobile-only">
      <LABEL for="q">Search</LABEL><BR>
      <INPUT name="q" id="q" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" ARIA-LABEL="Search" maxlength="150">
      <BUTTON class="btn btn-light btn-sm" type="SUBMIT">Go</BUTTON>
    </FORM>
    <UL class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/menu.php"); ?>
    </UL>
    <FORM action="/navigation/search.php" method="GET" ACCEPT-CHARSET="utf-8" target="_self" title="Search Hip Christmas" class="d-flex desktop-only">
      <LABEL for="q">Search</LABEL><BR>
      <INPUT name="q" id="q" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" ARIA-LABEL="Search" maxlength="150">
      <BUTTON class="btn btn-light btn-sm" type="SUBMIT">Go</BUTTON>
    </FORM>
  </DIV>
</NAV>

<!-- ////////// *** CONTENT CONTAINER *** \\\\\\\\\\ -->
<DIV id="page-content-wrapper">
  <MAIN>
    <DIV class="container" id="content">
      <DIV class="row content"> 
        <!-- ////////// *** MAIN CONTENT *** \\\\\\\\\\ -->
        <DIV class="col-md-8" id="main-content">
          <DIV id="google-page" class="mobile-only">
            <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/google-top.php"); ?>
          </DIV>
          
          <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/sharing.php"); ?>
           
          <ARTICLE> 
            <DIV class="clearfix"></DIV>
            
            
              
              
              
            
            
            <A id="body"></A><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Body-Content" -->
            <h1 class="offscreen">Hip Christmas</h1>
            <p style="clear:left"><A href="/about/index.php"><IMG src="/images/index/cowboy.gif" alt="Welcome to Hip Christmas!" class="thumb-left"></A><A href="/about/index.php" class="head">Welcome To Hip Christmas!</A> I think you'll enjoy my
              dysfunctionally vast web archive dedicated to holiday music that rocks, rolls, swings, and twangs. If you do, please support
              me by shopping at <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/amazon-link.php"); ?>, <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/itunes-link.php"); ?>,
              and <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/sheet-link.php"); ?>! Regardless, the best of
              the season to you - no matter what month it is! [<A href="/about/index.php">about me</A>]</P>
                
            <p style="clear:left"><A href="/annuals/new_releases/2024.php" class="head"><IMG src="/images/shared/baby_thumb.jpg" alt="What's New?" class="thumb-left">What's New In 2024?</A> Believe it or not, they've begun announcing new Christmas albums - lots of vinyl reissues, mainly - plus indie darlings <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0DDCTSH7P">Dean &amp; Britta</a> and the <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0DD1TFYQ9">Sunturns</a>, and a few big names like <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0DGV1TM7G">Jennifer Hudson</a>, <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0DHD9ZSG2">Clay Aiken</a>, and <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0DG365VH6">Little Big Town</a>. So, I've started my annual, obsessive, quixotic attempt to keep up with it all. Highlights also include a full-length <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0D81HW6BT">Tower Of Power</a> album, a new collection from the <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&amp;location=/dp/B0DG951NC4">Carpenters</a>, and yet another <a href="https://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?tag=randallanthon-20&location=/dp/B0D9YSG8YN">Bear Family</a> compilation. [<A href="/annuals/new_releases/2024.php">gimme&nbsp;gimme</A>]</p>
            <p style="clear:left"><a href="https://deanandbritta.bandcamp.com/merch/a-peace-of-us-listening-party" class="head"><IMG src="/images/index/dean_britta.jpg" alt="Facebook" class="thumb-left">This just in!</a> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/deanandbritta">Dean &amp; Britta</a> are having a <a href="{short URL removed}">listening party</a> on Nov. 17 at  4:00 PM CST for their much-anticipated Christmas album, <a href="[short URL removed]" class="title">A Peace of Us</a>, which arrives on Nov. 22. Dean, Britta, and their buddy Sonic Boom are members of indie rock darlings Galaxie 500, Luna, and Spacemen 3. Pre-order at <a href="[short URL removed]">Bandcamp</a>, <a href="https://amzn.to/3Ysnb9r">Amazon</a>, and around the web. [<a href="[short URL removed]">rsvp</a>]</p>
            <p style="clear:left"><A href="https://amzn.to/4eeVhUZ" class="head"><IMG src="/images/index/folds_ben1.jpg" alt="Facebook" class="thumb-left">Well, Now I'm Excited!</a> So far, the biggest news for me this year is Ben Folds' first-ever Christmas album, <a href="https://amzn.to/4eeVhUZ" class="title">Sleigher</a>. Most of the tracks are new,  original songs with his usual mix of pathos and humor - plus keen musicianship. Oh, and he lets AI write the lyrics for one of the songs! Read more in <a href="https://variety.com/2024/music/news/ben-folds-christmas-album-sleigher-1236155475/">Variety</a> and order the CD or vinyl at <a href="https://amzn.to/4eeVhUZ">Amazon</a>.</p>
            <p><A href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXdam5VrqMf3y" class="head"><IMG src="/images/index/spotify.jpg" alt="Spotify" class="thumb-left" />Spotify, Schmotify.</A> Once again, the company busy destroying the music industry is taking a breather to add  new new tracks to their ever-growing, <A href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXdam5VrqMf3y">exclusive holiday playlist</A>. It's free to stream, but you'll have to upgrade if you want to download. This year's biggest name is Kesha who does a nifty cover of Lindsay Buckingham's &quot;Holiday Road.&quot; [<A href="https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DXdam5VrqMf3y">spot&nbsp;me</A>]</p>
            <p style="clear:left"><A href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('/jukebox/wimpy_player.php','jukebox','width=395,height=275')" class="head"><IMG src="/images/index/jukebox.jpg" alt="Christmas Jukebox" class="thumb-left">The Christmas Jukebox.</A> My online Christmas music player is bulging with over 800 hip tunes - and counting! You can listen to the music I write about - the coolest, weirdest, and loudest holiday songs ever - all while enjoying my inimitable prose. [<A href="javascript:;" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('/jukebox/wimpy_player.php','jukebox','width=395,height=275')">press&nbsp;play</A>]</P>
            <p style="clear:left"><A href="https://www.facebook.com/HipChristmasMusic" class="head"><IMG src="/images/affiliates/facebook/logo-75.png" alt="Facebook" class="thumb-left">My Face, Your Book.</a> There's a lot of holiday hilarity going on over at <A href="https://www.facebook.com/HipChristmasMusic">Facebook</A>, in case you can't get enough on my website - or vice versa. Check out the <A href="https://www.facebook.com/HipChristmasMusic">Hip Christmas page</A>, and follow me for maximum holiday fun all year long. No Russian trolls, please. I also post cool cover art on <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hipchristmasmusic">Instagram</a> and <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/HipChristmas">Pinterest</a>. [<A href="https://www.facebook.com/HipChristmasMusic">follow&nbsp;me</A>]</p>

            <!-- content rotator --->         
              <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/index/rotator.php"); ?>
            <!-- end content rotator --->            

            <p style="clear:left"><A href="/annuals/christmas_gift/2023/index.php" class="head"><IMG src="/images/shared/gift_thumb.gif" alt="A Christmas Gift For You!" class="thumb-left">A Christmas Gift For You.</A> Every year, I offer five free MP3's from my voluminous collection - all unavailable easily or legitimately in the music marketplace. In 2023, I chose lost treasures by the Pretenders' Chrissie Hynde, XTC in disguise,  fake Rolling Stones, Boston's barbecue guru, and a Christmas bummer by Concrete Blonde. [<A href="/annuals/christmas_gift/2023/index.php">listen&nbsp;or&nbsp;download</A>]</p>
            <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
            
            
            
                      
            <P class="clearfix text-end no-print"> [<A href="/index-archive.php">old&nbsp;news</A>]&nbsp; [<A href="#top">top&nbsp;of&nbsp;page</A>]</P>
             </ARTICLE>
        </DIV>
        <!-- end main content --> 
        
        <!-- ////////// *** RIGHT SIDEBAR *** \\\\\\\\\\ -->
        <ASIDE class="col-md-4">
          <DIV class="sidebar"> 
            
            <!-- First Group of Sideboxes --> 
               
            <DIV class="sidebox">
              <H2>In The Spotlight</H2>
              <DIV class="spotlight">
                <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/spotlight/rotator.php"); ?>
              </DIV>
            </DIV>
             
             <!-- InstanceBeginRepeat name="Option-Repeat" --><!-- InstanceBeginRepeatEntry -->
            <DIV class="sidebox">
              <H2><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Option-Title" -->Christmas Jukebox<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></H2>
              <DIV> <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Option-Content" -->
                  <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/jukebox.php"); ?>
                  <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> </DIV>
            </DIV>
            <!-- InstanceEndRepeatEntry --><!-- InstanceEndRepeat --> 
             
            <!-- End first sidebox group --> 
            
            <!-- Facebook Feed - high on page --> 
            
            <SPAN class="container-lg p-0 text-center facebook-high">
            <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/facebook-feed.php"); ?>
            </SPAN>  
            <!-- End Facebook feed -->
              
            <!-- Sidebar --> 
             
            <!-- End Sidebar -->     
            
            <!-- Amazon Ads --> 
               <SPAN class="container-lg p-0">
            <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/affiliates/amazon-search-generic.php"); ?>
            </SPAN>    
            <!-- End Amazon ads --> 
            
            <!-- Second Group of Sideboxes --> 
             
            <DIV class="sidebox">
              <H2>In The Spotlight</H2>
              <DIV class="spotlight">
                <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/spotlight/rotator.php"); ?>
              </DIV>
            </DIV>
              
            <DIV class="sidebox">
              <H2>Latest Updates</H2>
              <DIV>
                <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/updates.php"); ?>
              </DIV>
            </DIV>
             
            <!-- End second optional group --> 
            </DIV>
            <!-- End flex sidebar --> 
            
            <!-- Facebook Feed - low on page --> 
             
            <!-- End Facebook feed --> 
            
            <!-- Google Bottom Ad --> 
             
            <!-- End Google ad --> 
            
          </ASIDE>
        <!-- end right sidebar --> 
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </MAIN>
  <!-- end content --> 
</DIV>
<!-- end content wrapper -->

<FOOTER class="container-fluid text-center">
  <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/footer.php"); ?>
</FOOTER>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP JAVASCRIPT --> 
<!-- link to Bootstrap CSS is in the header --> 
<SCRIPT src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" INTEGRITY="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" CROSSORIGIN="anonymous"></SCRIPT>
</BODY>
<!-- InstanceEnd --></HTML>



I am using a PHP script to select a limited number (15) of random files from a directory and then display them on a web page. The main problem is it seems to randomly misfire. Every few times I load the page, it displays more files than intended. Not a fatal error, but problematic.
Also, I haven't figured out a way to get it to not repeat the same files. Relying on the fact that I will eventually have hundreds of files to choose from.
Any ideas? I am not really a programmer...
Here is my script:
<?php 

    $folder = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/index/"); 

    $exts = 'php'; 

    $files = array(); $i = -1;  
    if ('' == $folder) $folder = './'; 
    $handle = opendir($folder); 
    $exts = explode(' ', $exts); 
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
    foreach($exts as $ext) { 
    if (preg_match('/\.'.$ext.'$/i', $file, $test)) { 
    $files[] = $file; 
    ++$i; 
    }
    }
    }

    shuffle($files);
    $random_keys=array_rand($files,15);
    require $files[$random_keys[0]];
    require $files[$random_keys[1]];
    require $files[$random_keys[2]];
    require $files[$random_keys[3]];
    require $files[$random_keys[4]];
    require $files[$random_keys[5]];
    require $files[$random_keys[6]];
    require $files[$random_keys[7]];
    require $files[$random_keys[8]];
    require $files[$random_keys[9]];
    require $files[$random_keys[10]];
    require $files[$random_keys[11]];
    require $files[$random_keys[12]];
    require $files[$random_keys[13]];
    require $files[$random_keys[14]];
?>


require is to include php code. Do you really want to include 15 random php code files?!?! That is SO random...
If you want to show text or html, use readfile().

You make a good point - I just need to rename the files (there's a bunch).

I have updated the logic and also added some conditions so that code can be debugged easily.
One more thing, you have fixed the limit to 15, what if there are less then 15 files? If you are sure there would be at least 15 files inside the folder then keep this.
Now, this code will load 15 different files each time when a user will refresh the page.
<?php
$folder = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/index/");
$exts = 'php';
$files = array();

if (is_dir($folder)) {
  $handle = opendir($folder);

  if ($handle) {
    $exts = explode(' ', $exts);

    while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
      foreach ($exts as $ext) {
        if (preg_match('/\.' . $ext . '$/i', $file, $test)) {
          $files[] = $file;
        }
      }
    }

    closedir($handle);

    if (count($files) >= 15) {
      shuffle($files);
      $random_keys = array_rand($files, 15);

      foreach ($random_keys as $key) {
        $file_path = $folder . $files[$key];

        if (file_exists($file_path)) {
          require $file_path;
          echo "<br>";
        } else {
          echo "File not found: " . $files[$key] . "<br>";
        }
      }
    } else {
      echo "Not enough PHP files in the directory.";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Unable to open directory: $folder";
  }
} else {
  echo "Directory does not exist: $folder";
}
?>


Interestingly, these solutions didn't solve the issue with the script firing twice - apparently randomly, every once in a while. I figure it's some sort of conflict, either elsewhere on the page, or on the serve side. Thanks again!

Can you please provide the complete code of the file? It will make easier to figure out the issue.

full code of page added at top. Rendered page at https://www.hipchristmas.com/index.php - thank you!

<?php 
    // Define folder path
    $folder = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/rotators/index/"); 
    $exts = 'php'; 
    
    $files = array(); 
    
    // Open the directory
    if (is_dir($folder)) {
        if ($handle = opendir($folder)) {
    
            // Filter for files with the given extension
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                $path_info = pathinfo($file);
                if (isset($path_info['extension']) && strtolower($path_info['extension']) === $exts) {
                    $files[] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    
    // Shuffle the array to randomize the file order
    shuffle($files);
    
    // Select the first 15 files, or however many are available
    $random_files = array_slice($files, 0, 15);
    
    // Loop through the selected files and include them
    foreach ($random_files as $file) {
        require $folder . $file;
    }
    ?>


use shuffle() to randomise the order

use array_slice() to pick the first 15 files

add error check to ensure there are enough files to display



Works perfectly - many thanks! I appreciate the annotation - helpful for content creators like me.
